# How to use keras with tensorboard but not through callbacks?

Tags: keras, tensorboard

Wand to use keras.backend.get_session() to log scalars and images to tensorboard. Session closes with I do this and keras errors out. I think there must be some way of getting the keras graph and doing things in it without breaking it.

Comment: Hi, I have same question, have you solved your problem? but I am using TF2, so there is no Session() anymore.